# Java SWING Not Painting Properly

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I'm having a problem with the JFrame not painting correctly. Can someone take a look at the solution please? I've tried using BoxLayouts but it wont work either. The buttons are not showing until I mouse over them.

It's all in one file and executable.

Regards

```
package Executable;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Whiteboard implements ActionListener 
{
JFrame frame;
public static Color drawColor = Color.BLACK;
public static String drawShape = "line";
JButton redButton, blueButton, blackButton, greenButton, circleButton,         lineButton, rectangleButton;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Whiteboard window = new Whiteboard();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Hw11()
{
    initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 686, 464);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel toolpanel = new JPanel();
    toolpanel.setBounds(10, 11, 652, 48);
    frame.getContentPane().add(toolpanel);
    toolpanel.setLayout(null);

    blackButton = new JButton();
    blackButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    blackButton.setBounds(10, 11, 89, 26);
    blackButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(blackButton);

    redButton = new JButton();
    redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    redButton.setBounds(101, 11, 89, 26);
    redButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(redButton);

    greenButton = new JButton();
    greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    greenButton.setBounds(192, 11, 89, 26);
    greenButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(greenButton);

    blueButton = new JButton();
    blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    blueButton.setBounds(283, 11, 89, 26);
    blueButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(blueButton);

    circleButton = new JButton("Circle");
    circleButton.setBounds(465, 11, 89, 26);
    circleButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(circleButton);

    lineButton = new JButton("Line");
    lineButton.setBounds(374, 11, 89, 26);
    lineButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(lineButton);

    rectangleButton = new JButton("Rect");
    rectangleButton.setBounds(555, 11, 89, 26);
    rectangleButton.addActionListener(this);
    toolpanel.add(rectangleButton);

    DrawPanel whiteboard = new DrawPanel();
    whiteboard.setBounds(10, 63, 652, 351);
    frame.getContentPane().add(whiteboard);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if (e.getSource() == redButton)
        drawColor = Color.RED;
    else if (e.getSource() == blueButton)
        drawColor = Color.BLUE;
    else if (e.getSource() == blackButton)
        drawColor = Color.BLACK;
    else if (e.getSource() == greenButton)
        drawColor = Color.GREEN;
    else if (e.getSource() == lineButton)
        drawShape = "line";
    else if (e.getSource() == circleButton)
        drawShape = "circle";
    else if (e.getSource() == rectangleButton)
        drawShape = "rect";
}
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
private Point p1, p2, p3;
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
Shape temp;

public DrawPanel()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    p1 = e.getPoint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    p2 = e.getPoint();
    Shape s = null;
    if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("line"))
    {
        s = new Line(p1, p2, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    else if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("circle"))
    {
        s = new Circle(p1, p2, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    else if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("rect"))
    {
        s = new Rectangle(p1, p2, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    shapes.add(s);
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    paint(g);
}

public void paintBackground()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.7f));
    paintBackground();
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    temp.draw(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
    {
        Shape s = shapes.get(i);
        s.draw(g);
    }
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    p3 = e.getPoint();

    if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("line"))
    {
        temp = new Line(p1, p3, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    else if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("circle"))
    {
        temp = new Circle(p1, p3, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    else if (Hw11.drawShape.equals("rect"))
    {
        temp = new Rectangle(p1, p3, Hw11.drawColor);
    }
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    paint(g);
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{

}
}

abstract class Shape
{
Point p1;
Point p2;
Color c;

public Shape(Point p1, Point p2, Color c)
{
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.c = c;
}

public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}

class Line extends Shape
{
public Line(Point p1, Point p2, Color c)
{
    super(p1, p2, c);
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(c);
    g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);//draw line p1 - p2
}

}


class Circle extends Shape
{
public Circle(Point p1, Point p2, Color c)
{
    super(p1, p2, c);
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(c);
    int r = (int)Math.sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x) + (p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y));
    g.drawOval(p1.x, p1.y - (r/2), r, r);//draw circle p1 - p2
}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape
{
public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Color c)
{
    super(p1, p2, c);
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(c);
    int width = p2.x - p1.x;
    int height = p2.y - p1.y;
g.drawRect(p1.x, p1.y, width, height);//draw rect p1 - p2
}
}
```

Comment: While executing i get a null pointer exception since temp is not set in DrawPanel.paintComponent (line 178).

Comment: I added a check `if (temp != null){ temp.draw(g);}` and ist working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Shape temp` is declared as a class field, but it is initialized in `public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)`. So it is null before first drag action, and in `temp.draw(g);`it gives an Exception.

Comment: Thanks && also thanks to Irene. What a rookie mistake -- Not checking the console!!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here beyond the NullPointerException.

You shouldn't be calling `paint` directly:

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
paint(g);
```

Use `repaint();` instead of `paint(getGraphics());`.

You shouldn't be modifying the `Graphics` passed in to `paintComponent`:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(...);
g2.setComposite(...);
```

This can carry over accidentally to other components besides the one you're attempting to paint.

Instead, create a copy:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

g2.setRenderingHint(...);
g2.setComposite(...);
...

// and dispose it at the end of paintComponent
g2.dispose();
```

You shouldn't be modifying the component state inside `paintComponent`:

```
public void paintBackground()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    ...
    paintBackground();
```

Doing this can cause an endless cycle of repaints because `setBackground` repaints if the color is different.

Instead, use `g.fillRect(...)` or `g.clearRect(...)`.

Comment: I miss there super.paintComponent as top one